# How to define date range that spans years, months in Django?

Tags: python, django, date, model, filtering

I have a Django model that contains a date field:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()
```

I'd like to have a manager on this model that shows only the events that occurred within a time period defined as July 1 (CURRENT YEAR) to June 31 (FOLLOWING YEAR).

So for this year, I'd want to return events beginning July 1, 2011 to June 31, 2012. And when the current date hits July 1, 2012, we'd show events happening to June 31, 2013.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from the docs:

```
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
Event.objects.filter(event_date__range=(start_date, end_date)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range

So the only challenge is figuring out what the current year is and adjusting the start and end date to reflect that. One manager approach:

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
     # Quick check to see what dates we should search within
     return super(EventManager, self).get_query_set().filter(event_date__range=(start_date, end_date))

class Event(models.Model):
    this_year = EventManager()
    ...
```

now you can query:

```
Event.this_year.all()
```

Comment: Yes, that's as far as I got using the docs. But how do I go about getting the start and end date dynamically? I'd rather not hard code this information.

Comment: If today is before the set date; start_date is (set day, set month, this year - 1) end date is (set day, set month,this year), else start_date is (set day, set month, this year) end date is (set day, set month, this year +1).